# Flutter: premasked input for phone number with underlines

Tags: flutter

How can I implement an input field with a predetermined mask as shown in the picture?

[image]

UPD: I need exactly dynamic replacement of placeholders ("_" symbol) so that when you type the first digit it replaces the first underscope, then the second, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mask_text_input_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter) to create the mask. Working example:

```dart
import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';

class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}

class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: TextField(
          inputFormatters: [MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: "+### ###-##-##")],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "+___ ___-__-__")),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I need exactly dynamic replacement of placeholders ("_" symbol) so that when you type the first digit it replaces the first underscope, then the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is RichText or with ROW and inputs for every part, you can move the focus after x number of chars to next input.

Comment: No, it is possible to achieve this using `inputFormatters`, but probably there is a ready solution